# Human Base Assets install problem

Tags: asset-browser

I have installed Blender 3.6 and downloaded the Human Base Mesh assets. I opened the blend and that works fine, but following the instructions of saving the asset library I get an error:

```
Unable to copy bundle due to 2 external dependencies; more details on the console
```

Then I check the console and it says:

```
Unable to copy bundle due to 2 external dependencies:
   "C:\Users\werne\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\blenderkit\thumbnails\vs_rejected.png"
   "C:\Users\werne\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\blenderkit\thumbnails\blenderkit_logo.png"
```

That's just two png files and I have no idea what it means that because of them the bundle cannot be copied.

I know I can technically just use the blend file to use the meshes but I would like to be able to save them to my asset library. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. If you go to your Outliner window, and then the Display mode to "Blender File", and then delete the problem files listed. Then you should be able to Copy the Bundle and Undo Deleting the files!